# Cygwin mintty fails to start, requires Cygwin install finalization to run properly

Tags: windows, windows-update, cygwin, software-update, mintty

I have a recurring problem using Cygwin (on a Windows 10 machine with a bunch of corporate spyware/malware which I had to live with).

Whenever I install or update Cygwin - everything seems to work fine, and I can start a terminal session. However, if I "leave it be" for a while - and possibly go through some auto-updates by Microsoft and/or by my employer - it stops working. That is, running:

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

has a window come up and immediately terminate itself. Updating cygwin rectifies the problem. I should also mention that, from a regular cmd shell session, I can run, say, `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe` (but then my paths are messed up somehow).

Why would this happening? And is there something I can do to prevent mintty from failing to run?

I can provide more information if necessary, just ask in a comment.

Comment: What happens using the `Cygwin.bat` in the Cygwin root folder ?

Comment: @matzeri: Good question. I'll try it next time I experience this problem and let you know. Right now I updated cygwin so it's working again.